# Watir :- click an image button?

Tags: watir, user-agent, firewatir, browser-automation

I have am using firefox and i have modified its user agent to make it behave like iphone web browser. now when i open google.com using watir and now i want to click on the searh button which is an image in mobile view. how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To click an image

```
<img id="logo">
```

try this

```
browser.image(:id => "logo").click
```

If the image is actually a button

```
<input type="image" id="logo">
```

try this

```
browser.button(:id => "logo").click
```

The next time please provide relevant HTML.

Also, take a look at [HTML Elements Supported by Watir](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir) page.